# WPF Data Virtualization

Tags: wpf, data-virtualization

I have a WPF DataGrid for which data comes from a stored procedure.  I want to know how can I virtualize that data?. I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework. My data in the database changes regularly and it needs to be fetched regularly through my stored procedure. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at [this post](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/10/11/SomeProgressWithFlyFetch.aspx) in order to see if it is useful to you. It is a generic solution to virtualize a collection. There is a sample too. Basically it works by proxing the data inside the collection to intercept when the UI observe the element, when it occours, a page is fetched. The only drawback is that the entity in the collection as to be declared as "proxable", so it must be public and with virtual properties.

Comment: Can I know how to do it using only the built in components of Visual Studio 2010. I want my data from my query to be virtualized.